# Is there a built-in function in Python or MySQL which returns a set of 3 frequently occuring words?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7, nltk

Is there a built-in function in python which returns "set of three frequently occuring words(consecutive)". I know how to do so programmatically but I am searching for a built-in function. Also I have these words stored in rows of 1 field in MySQL table, therefore I am searching for a solution in either python or MySQL.

E.g if my database contains users comments as fields, then I want to retrieve the 3 most frequently occuring consective words in those comments. One example of such 3 consecutive words is "I think that".
Also I know how to do it for 1 word, using SQL...but I have searched the previous posts and could not find for 3 consecutive words?

Comment: Do you want to return rows from your table where some field or another contains those three words consecutively? Do you know what those words will be ahead of time, or are they variable?

Comment: @DavidFaber Thanks for the reply. I am trying to find the 3 most frequently occuring word in that particular field of the database. E.g. in a database where comments are stored as fields, i want to find words like "Thanks for the"...considering my comment as an entry into that field.

Comment: So for 'You should be clearer in your examples' you want to increase the counters of 'You should be', 'should be clearer', 'be clearer in', etc.? :)

Comment: @EduardoIvanec Yes u r correct this is what i want to do...are there any build in methods for the same. Also thanks for replying :)

Comment: @user1172532: not that I'm aware of. See my answer for a somewhat Pythonic (list-comprehension-based) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no builtins for what you need, but this list comprehension should work and is quite succinct:

```
l = 'there are no builtins for that'.split()
print [" ".join(l[n:n+3]) for n in xrange(len(l)-2)]
['there are no', 'are no builtins', 'no builtins for', 'builtins for that']
```

Then, calling this last result `r`:

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter()
for item in r:
    c[item] += 1
print c
Counter({'there are no': 1, 'are no builtins': 1, 'no builtins for': 1, 'builtins for that': 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = 'zip can be used for that. Counter can be used as well'.lower().split()
>>> Counter(zip(l, l[1:], l[2:]))
Counter({('can', 'be', 'used'): 2, ('used', 'as', 'well'): 1, ('for', 'that.', 'counter'): 1, ('counter', 'can', 'be'): 1, ('be', 'used', 'for'): 1, ('zip', 'can', 'be'): 1, ('used', 'for', 'that.'): 1, ('be', 'used', 'as'): 1, ('that.', 'counter', 'can'): 1})
```

Now you can apply statistics:

```
>>> counter.most_common(1)[0][0]
('can', 'be', 'used')
```

Or if you want a joint string again:

```
>>> ' '.join(counter.most_common(1)[0][0])
'can be used'
```

Comment: Nice! Good use of zip. Better example too.

Comment: @Niklas B. Thanks for helping. But in my case "counter.most_common(1)[0][0]" is giving error. I am not getting where I am getting wrong. Please forgive my ignorance :)

Comment: @user1172532: What error? I assumed that you assign your `Counter` to it, like in `counter = Counter(zip(l, l[1:], l[2:]))`.

Comment: @Niklas B. Thanks a ton for the reply..and sorry again for my ignorance. Also if i have l="zip can be used for that. \n Counter can be used as well' that is I don't want that and Counter to be associated together, the way i am doing is splitting on '\n'...is there an easier way to tackle this. i.e if 'that' and 'counter' belong to different lines then they should not be associated together..sorry for troubling u again. :) and thanks again